# Multi case when for compare two dates Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I've a sql query that use "case when" for compare two dates and then assign value, my code works but I would like to know if can i make calculate once the date into case sentence and then only  evaluate value in the WHEN sentence.

Code works:

```
SELECT 
     O.ID
     CASE 
       WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(O.CREATED_AT) BETWEEN 1  AND 10 THEN 'start'
       WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(O.CREATED_AT) BETWEEN 11  AND 15 THEN 'proccesing'
       WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(O.CREATED_AT) BETWEEN 16  AND 30 THEN 'finish'
       ELSE 'expired'
     END AS State
FROM ORDER O
WHERE O.STATE > 2
```

And the next code throw next error "SQL Error [923] [42000]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

```
SELECT 
     O.ID
     CASE TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(O.CREATED_AT) as totaldays
       WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 1  AND 10 THEN 'start'
       WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 11  AND 15 THEN 'proccesing'
       WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 16  AND 30 THEN 'finish'
       ELSE 'expired'
     END AS State
FROM ORDER O
WHERE O.STATE > 2
```

my objective is make once the calculate per row, this is better than make calculate for each "case" sentence? or not there are difference the performance?

is there a way to do the calculation once and then evaluate the result?

Comment: The second isn't valid SQL, so it is not an option.  Stick with the code that runs.

Comment: In SQL  expression or builtin function performance is not the case, because most of the time is spend on reading, sorting, joining and aggregating the data

Comment: You need a comma after O.ID...

Comment: **Do not use *to_date(sysdate)***; sysdate is already a date. I suspect the same applies to the created_at column. If a column/variable is already a date there is never any need to convert to a date in fact strange very difficult to find errors may occur.

Comment: I was about to say that :-) `TO_DATE` exists to convert a string into a datetime (that Oracle calls `DATE` inappropriately). Maybe you want `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` and `TRUNC(O.CREATED_AT)` instead. to remove the time parts from the datetimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `TO_DATE` stuff in a *derived table*, and you'll save some typing, and have less error prone code:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 1   AND 10 THEN 'start'
            WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 11  AND 15 THEN 'proccesing'
            WHEN totaldays BETWEEN 16  AND 30 THEN 'finish'
            ELSE 'expired'
       END AS State
FROM
(
  SELECT 
       O.ID,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(O.CREATED_AT) as totaldays 
  FROM ORDER O
  WHERE O.STATE > 2
) dt
```

BTW, `ORDER` is a SQL reserved word, so that table name has to be qualified as `"ORDER"`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.)

**EDIT:** astentx suggested simplify as:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN totaldays <= 10 THEN 'start'
            WHEN totaldays <= 15 THEN 'proccesing'
            WHEN totaldays <= 30 THEN 'finish'
            ELSE 'expired'
       END AS State
FROM
(
  SELECT 
       O.ID,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(O.CREATED_AT) as totaldays 
  FROM ORDER O
  WHERE O.STATE > 2
) dt
```

Comment: `between` can be shortened further to `<= upper_boundary`

Comment: @astentx, of course... I'll add that version to the answer!

Comment: And `to_date(sysdate)`... no comments)

Comment: You mean it should be `sysdate - TO_DATE(O.CREATED_AT)`? (I've never used Oracle, I just wanted to show OP the derived table trick...)

Comment: Yes, sysdate is already a date and additional casting can cause errors sometimes. `1 - filter(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!))=SYSDATE@!)` [in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5cb671d702785e3b01e94a281008e68)

Comment: They probably want to remove the time part in order to subtract one date from the other and get full days (integers) thus: `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(O.CREATED_AT) as totaldays`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, was easy to adjust, when having a derived table!